# Matrix Error - "Field Limit is too big for your chosen Column Type"

Tags: matrix, error-message

I have a matrix field which is used a my main Body content field.
The site has just been updated to the latest version of Craft and I tried to add a block to the matrix field but when i try to save it I get the error on a plain text field:

```
Field Limit is too big for your chosen Column Type.
```

Even if i open the field and don't make any changes and jut save it I get the same error. The matrix field has 11 Block Types.

I have the same field in another website which actually has another couple of blocks in it and it can save without any issues.

I have found this thread: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2009 
and possibly related to a MySQL issue.

But is the issue related to the size of the Matrix Field? Or overall the number of fields in the database?

Comment: I deleted a number of unused fields and 3 unused sections from the database and i still get this issue trying to save the matrix field. the specific field which gives the error when saving the matrix field is already column type varchar.

Comment: I have changed the max characters on the field down from 255 to 60 and it lets me save it without changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is the issue related to the size of the Matrix Field? Or overall the number of fields in the database?

Neither. :)

That error message isn't related to the linked Github issue (although I can see how you'd get them confused).

It's coming from the Craft's Plain Text field type: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/fields/PlainText.php#L126-L137

There's a discrepancy between one of the Plain Text field's settings in your Matrix field where the `charLimit` setting on the field is greater than the database `Column Type` setting for that field can hold (i.e. for MySQL `varchar`, `text`, `mediumtext`, etc.).

Comment: After you have point it out what the issue is, and now re reading the error it is pretty obvious from the error message - what the issue was - daft.  A google search led me down the other path. Thanks